# R - Sample() with replacement produces observations with the same index

Tags: r, indexing, sample, indices

R - When trying to make a bootstrapping function using the function sample(data,replacement=TRUE). Observations that are resampled will have the same index, is it possible to reset all produced indices?

(R-newbie) What I actually was trying to do was to count the times a certain combination of categories was present in the newly sampled matrix. As I don't know a simple function to do it, I tried using a for-loop to iterate through the matrix. This provided a problem as duplicate observations will be counted only once.

This is an example of my resampled matrix (bsresampled): columns are (index,individual,stage,fate,births):

```
71            71    adult    adult         0
61.2          61    adult    adult         0
94.2          94    adult    adult         0
112          112    adult    adult         1
88            88    adult    adult         0
38.2          38 juvenile    adult         0
20.4          20 juvenile juvenile         0
57            57    adult    adult         0
```

And then I want to iterate through the data which obviously won't do what I want when duplicate indices exist

```
juvjuv = 0
juvad = 0
    for (i in 1:length(bsresampled)) {
      if(bsresampled$stage[i] == "juvenile" & bsresampled$fate[i] == 
"juvenile"){
        juvjuv == juvjuv +1
      }
      else if (bsresampled$stage[i] == "juvenile" & bsresampled$fate[i] == 
"adult"){
        juvad = juvad +1
      }
... #you get the idea
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to 'reset' the indices of my resampled matrix?

And/or is there an easier way to count the combinations I need?

Comment: `table()`  .... ?

Comment: Please post desired output with input sample you posted.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, table() seems like a good way to solve my problem, I'm trying it now thanks!